# Manage partials with handlebarsjs

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

i want use a partials with array but also a main template with arrays.

Main template:

```
<div id="notificationsRows" class="wrapper">
            {{#each notifications}}
                {{>notification}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
```

Row notification:

```
<div class="box-container-info">
    div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('{{image}}');"></div>
    <div class="info">{{message}}</div>
</div>
```

If I generate main i can generate with:

```
var context = {
    notifications: [{...},{...}]
}
```

Here not problem, but if I want add more notifications I can't call partial with array like

```
var moreContextForPartial =  [{...},{...}]; // This not works
```

I only can add each one like a object, not array:

```
var moreContextForPartial =  {...}; // This works
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to a partial - that has a context for a single row - to take your array of rows, which it cannot.
Try to ask to the main template, who has the iterator to do that task:

```
var moreNotifications =  [{...},{...}];
var wrapper = {notifications: moreNotifications };

var source   = $("#notificationRows").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var html = template(wrapper);
```

Comment: So, with this way that you writte i can move the each function inside the partial, and register the partil, not getting the html from body that this its slow.

Comment: If you want you can do that but at that point the main template becomes useless unless you don't write something else in it...